# Django, get sum of amount for the last day?

Tags: django, django-orm

```
class Point(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   expire_date = models.DateField()
   amount = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to know sum of amount for the last expire_date for a given user

There could be multiple `points` for a user and with same `expire_date`

I could do two query to get first last `expire_date` and `aggregate` on those. but wanna know if there's better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a subquery here:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Point.objects.filter(
    expire_date__gte=Point.objects.order_by('-expire_date').values('expire_date')[:1]
).aggregate(total=Sum('amount'))
```

This will thus result in a query that looks like:

```
SELECT SUM(point.amount) AS total
FROM point
WHERE point.expire_date >= (
    SELECT U0.expire_date
    FROM point U0
    ORDER BY U0.expire_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

I have not ran performance tests on it, so I suggest you first try to measure if this will improve performance significantly.

Comment: So just by putting the two queries in one statement makes it subquery opposed to two evalulated queries.

Comment: @eugene: usually yes, although some lookups force evaluation. You can inspect the query with `print(Point.objects.filter(..).query)`, or inspect the queries that Django sends to the database: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running